# Call a smart contract function using INFURA

Tags: node.js, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, evm

I can not understand how I can prepare the transaction, sign it and then send it using INFURA. I expect to get something wrong with the NodeJS code I posted. Can anyone kindly help me solve this problem?

Note: I am able to send the transaction on my smart contract, but the EVM reverts the execution.

Part of the Smart Contract (Solidity) (the function that I want to call):

```
function testFunction() public pure returns (string memory) {
    return "testSuccess";
}
```

The function used in NodeJS:

```
      const printRequestTransaction = async (gcodeHash) => {

    log(`Preparing a transaction to register that the gcode has been sent`.yellow);


    // With every new transaction send using a specific wallet address, it needed to increase a nonce which is tied to the sender wallet
    let nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(web3.eth.defaultAccount);

    // Fetch the current transaction gas prices from https://ethgasstation.info/
    let gasPrices = await getCurrentGasPrices();

    // Build a new transaction object and sign it locally
    let details = {
        "to": process.env.SMART_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
        //"value": web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei(amountToSend.toString(), 'ether')),
        "gas": 210000,
        "gasPrice": gasPrices.low * 1000000000, // converts the gwei price to wei
        "nonce": nonce,
        //"data": gcodeHash,
        "function": "testFunction",
        "chainId": 3 // EIP 155 chainId - mainnet: 1, ropsten: 3, rinkeby: 4 (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17051/how-to-select-a-network-id-or-is-there-a-list-of-network-ids/17101#17101)
    };
    const transaction = new EthereumTx(details);

    // This is where the transaction is authorized on Local PC behalf. The private key is what unlocks Local PC wallet.
    transaction.sign(Buffer.from(process.env.WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY, 'hex'));

    // Compress the transaction info down into a transportable object
    const serializedTransaction = transaction.serialize();

    // The Web3 library is able to automatically determine the "from" address based on Local PC private key

    // Submit the raw transaction details to the provider configured above (INFURA)

    const transactionHash = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTransaction.toString('hex')).then(function (receipt) {
        log(`result of the invokation: ${receipt})`.red);
        return receipt.transactionHash;
    }).catch((err) => {
        log(`error occurred: ${err})`.red);
    });

    //const transactionHash = "exampleHash";
    _transactionHash = transactionHash;

    // Now it is known the transaction ID, so let's build the public Etherscan url where the transaction details can be viewed.
    const url = `https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/${transactionHash}`;
    log(url.cyan);
    log(`Note: please allow for 30 seconds before transaction appears on Etherscan`.yellow)
};
```

Output:

> error occurred: Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
>                           {
>                             "blockHash": "0x6205c1b8ce2fde3693e85843dce684ff11472e9df01fd850bc99e5771b3262d5",
>                             "blockNumber": 5024524,
>                             "contractAddress": null,
>                             "cumulativeGasUsed": "0x50170f",
>                             "from": "0x8882528C7104e146E0500203C353C09922575385",
>                             "gasUsed": "0x5236",
>                             "logs": [],
>                             "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
>                             "status": "0x0",
>                             "to": "0x1732089F6F6EeFA942871707c5AE1909B60774EB",
>                             "transactionHash": "0xf748c9a6bdb19e776db4d8a9802d2bf5f8b588158da387029529249aca00a499",
>                             "transactionIndex": 1
>                           })

I would like to pay particular attention to the `let details = {...};` object for which I am not very sure it is correct, I have a little confusion about this.

Comment: What do you mean by `but the EVM refuses to perform`. The error message is clear. The EVM did perform but the transaction got reverted, probably by a `require` statement in the code. I am assuming that you are calling the above function which only has one require. Try to remove the require and see if anything changes.

Comment: I changed the function, so there is nor `require(...)` as you can see. I retrieve a very similar output error.

Comment: Does it still say that the transaction reverted? Also, I am not sure that your way of sending this transaction and the contents of the transaction are correct. Take a look at this answer for an example of calling a contract function this way.

Comment: The problem is int `details` object in which I defined `"function"` and the name of the funciont that I want to call. This seems to be wrong... maybe, I tried using: `const contractFunction = PrintProofOfWork.methods.printRequested(byte32gcodeHash);
    const functionAbi = contractFunction.encodeABI();` and put into details the field `data` this function ABI. Now the transaction works but I don know if the function of che smart contract is called or not...

Comment: Print out the returned value. But since you don't get any errors I am pretty sure it is called.

Comment: Ok, I couldn’t get exact data in this moment, but I remember that now it returns a `receipt` object which inside it there are some fields such as `transactionHash`, `from`, `to` and some others, but none of them are related to the function call result. I guess this receipt is related to the transaction and not to the function call like as in Remix IDE. I cannot use directly web3js and geth because I cannot open 30303 port so I have to use Infura.